# Could life and the world really be an electronic game being played in "eternity"?

Tags: metaphysics

Could beings in a larger world than ours be interacting with our world and with us in a game, creative experiment, or some learning exercise. Say each being has injected a part of himself into the electronic-type game or world, being this life and this world- this reality- so that within a whole unknown culture "out there", each of its members are responsible for guiding one of us as their character through the game or exercise. (The idea is vaguely similar to the backdrop of The Matrix movie- but the circumstances are a lot different.- and I'm not assuming that this view erases our moral responsibilities just because we "aren't real." To the contrary, we are real, but we are each a living piece of our larger self "out there."

All that digested, how likely do you think it is that our reality is a continual game or learning activity that some eternal beings are engaged in while we accept this as reality because- you'd have to tweak your character/avatar to actually believe this is reality, even if he is some small piece of your own consciousness. (I probably overdetailed that question again?)

Question: **How farfetched is it that reality is an eternal world where beings have invented our very, very convincing reality?**

Comment: I'm voting to close because there are too many questions here. However, I hope you keep bringing up questions. Make them specific, perhaps related to a particular text you are reading. That way the person answering the question can focus on that text and provide and answer in a few paragraphs with minimal personal opinion. Best wishes and welcome to this SE!

Comment: Yes. Great questions but too many to address.

Comment: Much worse. We're all characters in a video game in an alien college town bar. And they're about to run out of quarters.

Comment: Could it? I see no obstacle. Interesting, that I'm not alone in these thoughts. However, I'm much more certain.

Comment: I made an edit to make more clear what, I think, you want to know. However the question may still be closed as "primarily opinion-based". To rectify this you need to ground your inquiry on some substantive work, i.e. "What does a specific philosopher say?" or "What book can I read to learn about this?" Also it may be a **Duplicate**, which too can get it closed. I would encourage you to  search the questions for something like "Simulation"

Comment: isn't this the whole **solipsism** thing?  i s'pose we could be brains-in-vats.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the reality of individual moral responsibility makes this kind of hypothesis hard to accept.  If we were all truly one (in the unseen reality) then why are we so angry with each other?  Why is there so much hurt in the world?  Beyond that, why would major large-scale atrocities happen?

It is much more reasonable to believe that individuals are really individual, that harm is real, that people are vulnerable to each other because that is reality.  Supposing the reality of an omnipotent "god" who by-the-way is also us raises more problems than it solves.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I do not mean all truly one being. I meant each a tiny part of a lager being- EACH. Like we are ten people and there are ten beings, say. Each person is a piece of a corresponding being. No. Not all one being. Sorry about that.

Comment: Indeed, lol, it is simpler to believe that harm is real and that all we see is really as things are.

Comment: Ah, got it!  Thanks!  I won't delete, though, because it's a short answer, after all.

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely that physical reality is fake, because physical reality is our best explanation for the human conditions of regeneration and brain damage.

Human regeneration: If human beings were avatars, then how could two avatars (presumably reflecting beings that are separated in reality) cause a new hyper-being to begin to exist?  Why would the progeny of two avatars resemble parents in any way other than appearance or in any way that's not due to "nurture"?

Brain damage: why would physical causes impair the mental function of the hyper-beings?

It seems that this hypothesis raises more problems than it solves.  That is characteristic of a hypothesis that is not compelling.